# Java putting random symbols in my text file instead of integers

Tags: java, file, random, integer, symbols

I have a program that is supposed to put a string and random integer into a text file. For some reason my program is putting a random symbol into the file instead of an integer. Anyone know why this is happening?

What the file currently looks like:

```
Test
賬
Test2
∗
```

What the file should look like:

```
Test
36076
Test2
74263
```

Class that gets the string and random number:

```
public void newList() {

    boolean newCode = false;

    while (!newCode) {

        System.out.println("NEW LIST");
        System.out.print("List Name: ");

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        listName = scanner.next();

        System.out.println("The list name has been saved!");
        System.out.println();

        Random generateCode = new Random();
        setGeneratedCode(generateCode.nextInt((99999 - 10000) + 1) + 10000);

        File f = new File(generatedCode + ".txt");
        if (f.exists()) {
            newCode = false;
        }
        if (!f.exists()) {
            newCode = true;
        }
    }

    ListsWriter listsWriterObject = new ListsWriter();
    listsWriterObject.listsWriter(listName, generatedCode);
}
```

Class that writes the string and number to the file:

```
public void listsWriter(String listName, int generatedCode) {
    BufferedWriter bw = null;

    File lists = new File("lists.txt");

    try{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(lists, true);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        bw.write(listName);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(generatedCode);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();

    }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    FileCreator fileCreatorObject = new FileCreator();
    fileCreatorObject.fileCreator(generatedCode);
}
```

Comment: `write(int c)`
Writes a single character.

Comment: You need to cast generatedCode to a String, otherwise FileWriter/BufferedWriter will treat the int value as Unicode.

`bw.write("" + generatedCode);`

Comment: Side note: `Random generateCode = new Random();` should be outside the loop, otherwise you're just starting the pseudorandom sequence over each time.

Comment: Side note: `if (f.exists()) { newCode = false; } if (!f.exists()) { newCode = true; }` could be sooo much simpler: `newCode = ! f.exists();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the write(int c) method of the [OutputStreamWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write(char[]))

> `write(int c)`
>
> Writes a single character.

You need to convert it, for example to a `String` and use this:

`bw.write(String.valueOf(generatedCode))`

Answer (score 0):

the write method of BufferedWriter write a character:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html

you must convert your int to string:

```
bw.write(Integer.toString(generatedCode));
```